# Dynamic text fields values into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, field

I have a dynamic web form that creates text after the user tells it how many he wants, what I want to do, is to get the info of those text fields into the next form, I've read a question that is 
[pretty much what I want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784015/javascript-php-dynamic-text-fields-jquery); 
But I haven't had any luck so far;

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {
echo "<input type='text' class='text' name='classEmpleado[]' id='empleado$i' />";}
```

When I try to retrieve them I use this;

```
$empleado[] = $_POST['classEmpleado[]'];
$i = 0;    
for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {
echo "$empleado[$i]<BR><BR>";
}
```

But I get the error Undefined index: classEmpleado[] 
What am I doing wrong?

ANSWERED!
For anyone looking for the same thing, look at the response of Sherbrow,
And you would just have to edit the loop to this

```
$empleado[] = $_POST['classEmpleado[]'];
$i = 0;    
for ($i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++) {
echo "$empleado[$i]<BR><BR>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$empleado` is not previously declared or just empty, you are looking for that

```
$empleado = $_POST['classEmpleado']
```

But if `$empleado` is an array, and contains data, you may want to merge everything in one only array

```
$empleado = array_merge($empleado, $_POST['classEmpleado']);
```

Whichever way you choose, there should be a check to be certain that `$_POST['classEmpleado']` is defined and is an array. Something like :

```
if(isset($_POST['classEmpleado']) && is_array($_POST['classEmpleado'])) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$empleado[] = $_POST['classEmpleado'];`

When you put `name[]` at the end of the fieldname, it will be passed to PHP as an array in `$_POST` with the key of `name` like so: `$_POST['name'] = array(1,2,3,4);`

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks, but I had to write it likeSherbrow explained in the answer below,     $empleado = $POST['classEmpleado'];

Answer (score -1):

This statement here is wrong (`$empleado[] = $_POST['classEmpleado[]']`)

If you want to access $_POST the input field named classEmpleado[], you have to do so :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['classEmpleado']); $i++)
{
    echo $_POST['classEmpleado'][$i] . '<br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: This will be the structure of $_POST array :

`Array
(
    [classEmpleado] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text 0
            [1] => Some text 1
            [2] => Some text 2
        )
)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try this in another web form that I intend on making, appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't put `count()` inside the loop condition, it will get executed EVERY iteration of the loop.